# calculating percentages method

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `List<string>`, with strings randomly from A-F. ("A", "D", "B", "A", etc.)

I want to know what percentage of the total, for A-F.

I'm working in visual studio C#, WinForms, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet? what code do you have so far?

Comment: You mean, how much % are "A"s, how much % are "B"s of the total list?

Comment: Is it homework? What have you tried?

Comment: Seems link a homework for me ... well create another list to keep trace of the letters count then dividing that number of each letter count on the original items count ... you will get what you are looking for :)

Comment: Are the strings always single characters?

Comment: Its not homework! And yes, I've tried to do it, but I'm new to coding, so everything is not as easy as YOU guys thinks of it! The strings are ALWAYS single characters, and I want to know for example: How many of the lists total strings are A, and how many are B.

Comment: @AndersJensen - In the future please post your past attempts

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var groups = strings.ToLookup(str => str); 
var percentages = groups.Select(group => 
  new { Str = group.Key, Pct = (group.Count() * 100 / strings.Count)});
```

Comment: I don't believe this question is worthy of such an excellent answer

Comment: Why? Study,study,and study again as said Lenin) This code is good for education

Comment: Because they're clearly haven't already attempted the problem - merely looking for a quick answer

Comment: @m.edmondson you dont know how much I've tried to solve this. Just because i'm new to this stuff, doesnt mean that I dont put the effort in it.

Comment: @AndersJensen - Ok fair enough, but you should post what you've already done.  On the question page it clearly states: `Provide details. Share your research.`